# Map array object values to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that contain a property called **rates** and inside each objects rates array are id's (among other properties, not shown here for simplicity). How can I map these id's to a new array so that I have a record of all id's returned in all objects rates?

```
 const sampleResponse = [
   {
     id: '123',
     rates: [{ id: '123' }, { id: '456' }]
   },
   {
     id: '456',
     rates: [{ id: '789' }, { id: 'ABC' }]
   },
   {
     id: '789',
     rates: [{ id: 'DEF' }, { id: 'GHI' }]
   }
 ]
```

**Expected Result**

```
const result = ['123', '456', '789', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.concat()` combines with `.map()` to achieve it.

```js
const sampleObject = [
 {
   id: '123',
   rates: [{ id: '123' }, { id: '456' }]
 },
 {
   id: '456',
   rates: [{ id: '789' }, { id: 'ABC' }]
 },
 {
   id: '789',
   rates: [{ id: 'DEF' }, { id: 'GHI' }]
 }];
 
 let result = [];
 for(let item of sampleObject){
    result = result.concat(item.rates.map(r => r.id));
 } 
console.log(result);
```

Or [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this way

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
> each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

```js
const sampleObject = [
 {
   id: '123',
   rates: [{ id: '123' }, { id: '456' }]
 },
 {
   id: '456',
   rates: [{ id: '789' }, { id: 'ABC' }]
 },
 {
   id: '789',
   rates: [{ id: 'DEF' }, { id: 'GHI' }]
 }];
 
 const result = sampleObject.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.rates.map(r => r.id)), []);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const sampleObject = [
  {
    id: '123',
    rates: [{ id: '123' }, { id: '456' }],
  },
  {
    id: '456',
    rates: [{ id: '789' }, { id: 'ABC' }],
  },
  {
    id: '789',
    rates: [{ id: 'DEF' }, { id: 'GHI' }],
  },
];
const ret = sampleObject.flatMap((x) => x.rates.map((y) => y.id));
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Flat Map does not look to be supported in IE :/ I'd like it to work on all browsers

Comment: @Michael you tagged this question with `ecmascript-6`

Comment: ah you're right! my mistake, this will work. thank you!

Comment: Alternative, [straight from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#alternative)

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` and `destructuring`

```js
const rateIds = (arr, output = []) => {
  arr.forEach(({ rates }) => rates.forEach(({ id }) => output.push(id)));
  return output;
};

const sampleResponse = [
  {
    id: "123",
    rates: [{ id: "123" }, { id: "456" }],
  },
  {
    id: "456",
    rates: [{ id: "789" }, { id: "ABC" }],
  },
  {
    id: "789",
    rates: [{ id: "DEF" }, { id: "GHI" }],
  },
];

console.log(rateIds(sampleResponse));
```